# iTunes connect - additional price tiers 1b 2b

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, price

I know about the alternate price tiers that can be chosen from, but apart from the alternate tiers, there are two additional tiers appearing in iTunes connect called "1b" and "2b" (see picture below). I could not find these additional tiers in any documentation ... !?

[image: additional tiers]

It's defiantly not the alternate A B tiers, as these are appearing at the end of the list (see picture below).

[image: alternate price tiers]

In the application loader these additional price tiers 1b and 2b are not showing up:

[image: application loader]

I'm a bit uncertain if I should choose "1" or "1b"!? What is the difference? So it would be great if someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you found the solution after 18 month. 
As I had the same problem here is the solution I applied :

- created a product in application loader.
- Added it Alternate tier 1
- Recovered the package
- opened it
- Got the value : 550
- Added the value in my text file.
- Sent it to apple and was accepted. 
  Tested only with Application loader 3.0, but should work with 3.6 once you have the metadata value.

Answer (score 0):

The additional tier category is occuring, because you have a specific deployment country, which offers a finer grained price tier set. E.G: CHina has got for Price tier 1: 1 ¥ and for Price tier 1b: 3¥
Whilst the US just got 1 tier with $0.99

There is a release note from Apple, informing about the fact:
https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=01272016a

You can see a great overview of all different tiers, countries and currencies on a page hosted by equinux:
http://www.equinux.com/us/appdevelopers/pricematrix.html

Which basically accumulates all information from apples notes:
https://itunespartner.apple.com/assets/downloads/Apps_PricingSchedule_January2016.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've checked your links but could not find these additional tiers that show up at my iTunes connect. I've modified my question to make it more clear what I'm struggling with.

Comment: Dear Hecot, sorry for the inconvenience. The list is embedded in a scrollview. Please CMD+F for "Alternate Tier" and you will see the detailed listing on the equinux page. As example I have a screenshot with mexican pesos (I think it is) https://www.dropbox.com/s/sdvnkzq86ojmpgx/Screen%20Shot%202017-01-02%20at%2016.41.47.png

Comment: Dear Lepidopteran, thanks for the picture, but these alternate A B are also showing up. I've modified my question again to make clear what I don't understand. There are two more options "1b" and "2b" that are not showing up when using the application loader (see my modified question above)